# How to send arguments to bash script in GNU parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I want to use GNU parallel to execute some commands in parallel, but I don't know how to send the argument to my bash scripts.

My bash_script.sh:

```
scp $1.zip xxx@1.com:~/
scp $1.zip xxx@2.com:~/
scp $1.zip xxx@3.com:~/
scp $1.zip xxx@4.com:~/
scp $1.zip xxx@5.com:~/
```

I can send the argument to the bash_script and execute it in sequence.

```
bash bash_script.sh argument
```

but how to do it in parallel?

```
parallel -a bash_script argument
```

Comment: I hope the bash_script is not a static text, and I want to use an argument outside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bash_script.sh**

```
parallel scp "$1" xxx@{}.com: ::: {1..5}
```

**Usage:**

```
bash bash_script.sh argument
```

Comment: This basically duplicates my answer (except you had botched the quoting).

Comment: (The `~/` is redundant because `scp` by default copies to the user's home directory.)

Comment: Your answer just give me the idea that I should put the parallel command inside the script rather than execute in shell. The concept is different. Your answer doesn't set the argument as a dynamic script, and I need a dynamic one and that's the whole point.

Comment: Please review the link I provided which explains why removing the quotes is wrong. Your script will not work with file names which contain whitespace, wildcard characters, or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: Anything you can type at the prompt, you can put in a script, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

`parallel` can execute individual *processes* in parallel, but a script is usually intended to be run as a single process.

You could do

```sh
parallel scp "$1" xxx@{}1.xyz.com: ::: {1..5}
```

or if you really wanted to split the script file into individual lines

```sh
sed "s#\$1#$1#g" bash_script.sh | parallel
```

If the script was just static text, you could simply have `parallel` read it line by line; but `parallel` doesn't have a value for `$1` in that context, so we substitute it in, and then piped the substituted lines for parallel execution.

Tangentially, notice [proper variable quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and don't put a `.sh` extension on a Bash script. (Don't put any extension on any script, basically.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
for server in server1 server2 server 3
do
   scp "$1" $server: &
done
```

The `&` causes the job to run in the background. If I'm not understanding your requirements, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is writing the commands to a text file (e.g: commands.txt) and the executing **parallel**:

```
parallel -j 2 < commands.txt
```